# Rails 4, setting up CSS background image

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I want to set a background image via the CSS `background: url()` property. But it isn't working. There is nothing special. I have done:

```
-rails new myApp
-rails g controller Welcome index.
```

That's it. I have this div:

```
<div class="image">
```

And the CSS for it is:

```
.image{
    background: url('image.jgp');
}
```

I have image.jgp on my assets/images folder. I can do `<%= image_tag('assets/image.jgp')` and it works. But the CSS part doesn't work.
How could this problem be solved?

Comment: Shouldn't the image filename end with `.jpg` instead of `.jgp`?

Answer (score 0):

You have not properly provided the path to the image.

```
.image{ background: url(../assets/image.jgp); }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have wrong image extention "jgp".. Try to rename it with "jpg".

Comment: It is a typo.I got the right one on the app.Still no :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way, add extension *.erb to your css/scss file (for example *session.scss.erb*)

After you are able to write this code

```
.image {    
background-image: url(<%= asset_path('image.jpg') %>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the path to images pointing the asset folder like this

```
.image{ background: url(assets/image.jgp); }
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.